# Getting Redirect Loop Error for the Header

Tags: php, loops, redirect

I am getting a redirect Error for the following code. It's just that when the form is submitted and certain username is checked, it should redirect to a certain page.

```
<div>
<?php
    global $user;
    if (isset($user->name)) { 
        echo "You don't have permission to access the administrator with the current logged in user (".$user->name."). ". "<a href='./user/logout'>Log Out as (" .   $user->name . ")</a>"."<br /><br />";
    }
?>
Please refer to the credentials sent to you.</div>

<?php
if ($user->name == "a-particular-user") {
        header( 'Location: http://url.to.direct' ) ;
    }

?>
```

### On the Redirect Page, following code exits

```
   global $user;

$adminuser = false;
if (in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles)))
    $adminuser = true;

if ( !($adminuser) && ($user->name != "rockstar")) {
    echo "<br /><br />";
    echo "<h2> You need to be an Administrator to see this page.</h2>";
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Is this code on the same page as the redirect page?

Comment: Hi Gerve, just edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the code is in the same page as the one you're redirecting to. It causes a loop.

You can solve this with a GET variable:

```
if ($user->name == "a-particular-user" && !isset($_GET['adminpage'])) {
    header( 'Location: http://url.to.direct?adminpage=true' ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you ask a question about an error message you're getting, but not include the error message?

Does the error message say something about "headers already sent"?

You can't use `header()` to redirect after you've already generated content, even if it's only a space or a blank line.  In this case, you have a `<div>` in the first line no matter what else happens.  So, you won't be able to send a `header()` after that.

ref: [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Comment: Because, this form is being used for more than one purpose.

Comment: @Steve The purpose of the form doesn't matter. You can't use `header()` after other output has already been sent. Another ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php